# Are my YouTube "Likes" public to my contacts on Google+?

Tags: youtube

On the new YouTube interface, when I go to the `Social` tab, I can see the items that my contacts on Google+ have `+1`ed and `shared`.

Also, if I go to my profile and click on `Likes` I can see a list of the videos on which I clicked on the `Like` button.

My question is:

- Are my `Likes` (thumbs up) or `Dislikes` (thumbs down) public?
- Does Google keep my `Likes` separate from my `+1`'s?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe they (your Google Plus connections' likes) can see your likes. Only the shares of videos via Google Plus are viewable.

Yes, Google keeps your likes and +1's separate.

Comment: Need something to back this.